# variable inside brackets powershell

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation, quoting

I am struggling on this for hours now ...

Its a syntax question basically how do I make this work : `$test = '{"Title": $name}'`
The `$name` is not recognize as a variable.
this is a simple example the real line is here and the unrecognize var is the $li at the end:

```
Add-PnPPageWebPart -Page "Home.aspx" -DefaultWebPartType ContentRollup  -Section 3 -Column $counter -WebPartProperties '{"query": {"contentLocation": 4,"contentTypes": [1],"sortType": 1,"filters": [{"filterType": 1,"value": "","values": []}],"documentTypes": [1,2,3,10],"advancedQueryText": ""}, "listTitle": $li}'
```

Thanks to those who will help :)

Comment: Yes, switch the quotes to double quotes. Interpolation doesn't occur in single quotes. So either switch the quotes, or escape the double quotes `"""{...}"""`.

Comment: In short: In PowerShell, only `"..."` strings (double-quoted aka _expandable strings_) perform string interpolation (expansion of variable values and expressions), not `'...'` strings (single-quoted aka _verbatim strings_). With `"..."` quoting, if the string value itself contains `"` chars., escape them as `\`"` or `""`, or use a double-quoted _here-string_.  See the conceptual [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) help topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a double-quoted here-string:

```
$test = @"
{"Title": $name}
"@
```

Or use a regular double-quoted string, and then escape the literal `"`'s, by either doubling them:

```
$test = "{""Title"": $name}"
```

... or by using a backtick `` ` ``:

```
$test = "{`"Title`": $name}"
```